# dropbox login fail startOAuth2Authentication

Tags: android, dropbox

I have implemented in my app an access to dropbox, when I try to connect (login), the browser web interface don't start and , I receive this message on logcat.
How can find the bug?

This is a part of the code:

```
    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
                mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

   btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        btnUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        if (mLoggedIn) {
                            logOut();
                        } else {
                            // Start the remote authentication
                            mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(MainScelta.this);
                        }
                         // Display the proper UI state if logged in or not
                        setLoggedIn(mApi.getSession().isLinked());
                        //Toast.makeText(appContext, getString(R.string.desc_login), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    }
                });


05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665): java.lang.VerifyError: com/dropbox/client2/RESTUtility
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity.startWebAuth(AuthActivity.java:506)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity.onResume(AuthActivity.java:372)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-13 16:36:33.915: E/AndroidRuntime(1665):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Question answered in comments or edits. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> You need to add all of the jars included in the lib folder of the SDK, as opposed to only dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar.